# Referencing to the second dimension of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I've got this class and a two dimensional array of it's objects:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x)
    {
        value = x;
    }
    int value;
};

Foo foo1(1), foo2(2), foo3(3), foo4(4);
Foo* fooArray1[4][2] = { {&foo1, &foo2}, {&foo2, &foo3}, {&foo3, &foo4}, {&foo4, &foo1} };
```

Now I want to reference to the second dimension of this array.
Somehow:

```
Foo* fooArray3[2] = fooArray1[2];
```

But my compiler keeps telling me:

```
Unallowed Assignment »Foo* (*)[2]« to »Foo* [2]«
```

The only version i got to work was:

```
Foo** fooArray2 = fooArray1[3];
```

But with this version I have to access fooArray2 with the star operator, what I don't want to:

```
cout << "fooArray2[0]: " << (*fooArray2)[0].value << " fooArray2[1]: " << (*fooArray2)[1].value << endl;
```

Comment: you have it the wrong way around. it should be (*fooArray2[1]).value or using the arrow operator. The order you use causes undefined behavior.

Comment: `(*fooArray2)[0].value` is just illogical, you want `(*(fooArray2[0])).value` or equivalent: `fooArray2[0]->value`.

Comment: Thank you! fooArray2[0]->value is nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
Foo* (&fooArray3)[2] = fooArray1[3];
std::cout << fooArray3[0]->value; // Prints 4
```

If you're using C++11, however, life is much more pleasant:

```
auto& fooArray3 = fooArray1[3];
std::cout << fooArray3[0]->value; // Prints 4
```

**EDIT:** As requested:

```
Foo* (*fooArray3)[2];
⋮
fooArray3 = &fooArray1[3];
std::cout << (*fooArray3[0])->value;
```

Comment: Currently I can't use C++11. Could you give another example where you initialize fooArray3 with (0/NULL) and assign it in a seperate statement? Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for the Edit. But This will use * at the cout. This was I don't wanted to. So I think I'm going to use the Foo** version with -> as suggested by Antoine

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want **pointer to an array**. 2nd dimension of `fooArray1` constitutes 2 elements. There is a special syntax for that as below:

```
Foo *(*fooArray3)[2] = &fooArray1[2];  // compiles
```

Above syntax means: `fooArray3` is a *pointer to a pointer to array of 2 `Foo` elements*.

However I believe you may not want this much complex syntax. You should change your design where you can hold the data with simple data types or `std` containers.

Comment: Yeah, this compiles. Thanks! But could you make an example how to access elements of fooArray3 with cout? (Btw: Foo is a more complex class in the Program I'm maintaining)